# JavaFx: fxgraph PropertyValueFactory -> cellValueFactory

Tags: javafx, tableview, fxml

I use in a JavaFX eclipse project FXGraphs. Now I wanna use a `TableView`. Therefore I wrote this *Sample.fxgraph* file (only tableview part):

```
TableView < Customer > {
  columns : [
    TableColumn < Customer, Integer > {
      text : "Id",
      PropertyValueFactory < Customer, Integer > {
        cellValueFactory {
          property : "id"
        }
      }
    },
   TableColumn < Customer, String > {
      text : "Family name",
      PropertyValueFactory < Customer, String > {
        cellValueFactory {
          property : "familyName"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now the *Sample.fxml* file should be like this (only tableview part):

```
<TableView>
  <columns>
    <TableColumn text="Id">
      <cellValueFactory>
        <PropertyValueFactory property="id" />
      </cellValueFactory>
    </TableColumn>
    <TableColumn text="Family name">
      <cellValueFactory>
        <PropertyValueFactory property="familyName" />
      </cellValueFactory>
    </TableColumn>
  </columns>
</TableView>
```

Howerver there is an error "**cellValueFactory cannot be resolved to a type.**" in the *Sample.fxgraph* file. Thats not an import problem. The program runs with the correct fxml-file. How can I fix it?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I'm not familiar with fxgraph, but `cellValueFactory` is not a property of `PropertyValueFactory` but of `TableColumn`. Shouldn't it be something like `text: "Id", cellValueFactory: PropertyValueFactory....`

Comment: Thanks. Worked well. Can you please write this as answer (so I can close this silly question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved by the comment from @fabian.

```
TableView < Customer > id tableView {
    columns : [
        TableColumn < Customer, Integer > id idTableColumn {
            text : "Id",
            cellValueFactory : PropertyValueFactory < Customer, Integer > {
                property : "id"
            }
        },
        TableColumn < Customer, String > {
            text : "Family name",
            cellValueFactory : PropertyValueFactory < Customer, String > {
                property : "familyName"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```